# Differences in domain for definition of real multivariable limit

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

1. For the definition of $\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,y_0)}g(x,y)=L$ below, is the following correct?

   - 1.1.

   > Let $g$ be a real function defined on an open deleted neighbourhood of some point $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb R^2$.

   - 1.2. I understand the above translates to

   > Let $G \subseteq \mathbb R^2$. Let $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb R^2$. Let $g: G \to \mathbb R$. Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0)$ with $U \ \setminus \{(x_0,y_0)\} \subseteq G$.

   - 1.3. Then $\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,y_0)}g(x,y)=L$ is defined as

   > For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ s.t. $|g(x,y)-L| < \varepsilon$ whenever $0 < \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2} < \delta$ and $(x,y) \in $ (either $G$ or $U$ or $U \ \setminus \ \{(x_0,y_0)\}$ - **not sure? see next**)
2. As for $G$, $U$ or $U \ \setminus \ \{(x_0,y_0)\}$, does it make a difference?

   - 2.1. I think there's no difference between $U$ or $U \ \setminus \ \{(x_0,y_0)\}$ because we already have '$0 <$'.
   - 2.2. As for $G$ and $U$, not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right there's no difference between $U$ or $U \ \setminus \ \{(x_0,y_0)\}$ because we already have the strict inequality.

For the second issue, keeping the restriction to $U$ we should refer to it but we can also not consider the restriction to $U$ using that $0 < \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2} < \delta$ and $(x,y) \in G$.

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon Yes in this case we are considering a restriction of the function around the limit point $f:U\subseteq G \to \mathbb R^2$ and this is fine.

Comment: Note: user is responding to a comment which said something like 'thanks user! does it really have to be $U$ instead of $G$? please consider helping in the [complex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268942/what-exactly-are-the-differences-between-real-multivariable-limits-and-complex-l) case'. maybe i accidentally deleted the comment without posting an edited version.

Comment: user, what's an example of a problem if we use $G$ instead of $U$ please?

Comment: user are you sure it's $U$ instead of $G$? in the [complex version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268942/what-exactly-are-the-differences-between-real-multivariable-limits-and-complex-l) it is $G$ i believe

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon For example some point near $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $f$ blows out.

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon I'll take a look also to this! What is the reference for the version you are using here?

Comment: thanks! for the real limit: it's a combination of my class notes and stewart calculus. but i'm trying to make the definition to be a little more precise with the domains, where $z$ is, etc. for the complex limit: combination of class notes and brown churchill

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon In this form the definition is fine. But I understand your doubt and we can also eliminate $U$ by the definition using that $0 < \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2} < \delta$ and $(x,y) \in G$.

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon I've update answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks user. anyway bottom line the definition is the same/equivalent for $(x,y) \in G$ vs $(x,y) \in U$ vs $(x,y) \in U \ \setminus \ (x_0,y_0)$?

Comment: For the definition we don’t need to introduce $U$ ( not wrong but unnecessary), therefore $(x,y)\in G$ is fine.

Comment: user, in what way is $U$ unnecessary? we want an open set involved right? do you mean to assume $z_0$ is a limit point of $G$? do you mean to assume $G$ is open in $\mathbb C$? or what? Note that $G$ isn't a region or domain or whatever. It's just subset of $\mathbb C$ that happens to be the domain of a complex function.

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon Because by the condition$ 0 < \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2} < \delta$ with $(x,y) \in G$ we are selecting points in a open ball around $(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: user, i (sort of) asked my instructor about this earlier. does this make a difference for real or complex re the $U$ is unnecessary given $G$?